# Which part of a recursive algorithm actually describes how to do something and terminate?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I think base case is the right answer.
Do you think so?

or base basket / standard method / default mode / none of the mentioned?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_functions_and_algorithms

The standard recursive algorithm for a DFS is:

base case: If current node is Null, return false
recursive step: otherwise, check value of current node, return true if match, otherwise recurse on children
In short-circuiting, this is instead:

check value of current node, return true if match,
otherwise, on children, if not Null, then recurse.

Comment: From your Wikipedia link: `"base cases ... for which the function produces a result trivially (without recurring)"` - "return true if match" is a non-recurring production of a result and thus a base case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say "actually describes how to do something" - the entire recursive algorithm does that.

Comment: If it is the definition you are looking for it is 'base case'. To be precise the base case is expressed without recursion as we know the result of it. All other things you mentioned are implementation of recursive function.

Comment: Thanks guys, I also try to figure out, to be sure. 
The question is not mine; I do not have the possibility to ask directly.

Comment: The question asks for "how to do something AND terminate", so the answer would be base case AND recursive step and therefore none of the mentioned answers would be correct.